# How to send message content when a router got hit it will send the first content then the second

Tags: php, laravel

Actually I want to send message when A page is hit. Like I have a page called numbers.blade.php. Here is the route

```
Route::get("/numbers", [\App\Http\Controllers\NumberController::class, 'get_numbers_from_ringba'])->name("numbers");
```

When I will get to this route a message will be sent.
Here is the code:

```
 public function get_numbers_from_ringba()
    {
        $numbers = Number::all();
        $contents = array(
            "We apologize that your call was dropped. We have qualified you for a simple, low-cost health insurance plan. Contact us at +18883470772 again within 1 minute to find out more about your free, no-risk health insurance plan!",
            "Hi, Congratulations! As an apology for the dropped call, We are currently offering you a limited time 20% discount on the ACA Insurance Plan, just for you! Please reach us again at +18883470772. Grab the Lifetime HealthCare Opportunity within a Minute!",
            "Still not Happy with our 20% discount? We have reserved a special enrollment opportunity just for you and your family (all-inclusive medical protection & 25% Discount)! Reduce your chances of becoming ill or injured with ACA, as 14.5 million US citizens have done. Call Now: +18883470772 before the offer expires Today!",
            "We do not want to bother you, just following up about our ACA plan. We can help get your ACA health insurance fixed so your life is more manageable. If you apply today, you might be able to get free health insurance through the Marketplace. Call us +18883470772",
            "Hey there! It’s our final follow-up from our end. Do you still wish to proceed? We are always here to assist you. Call us +18883470772 without any hesitation."
        );
        $twilio_sid = getenv("TWILIO_SID");
        $twilio_token = getenv("TWILIO_TOKEN");
        $client = new Client($twilio_sid, $twilio_token);
        foreach ($numbers as $number) {
            $client->messages->create(
                $number->callerId,
                //"+14356277657",
                [
                    "from" => "+18882998227",
                    "body" => $contents[1]
                ]
            );
        }


        return view("Dashboard.Numbers.numbers", [
            "numbers" => $numbers
        ]);
    }
```

So, here you can see $contents variable. There are some contents inside of an array. When Someone get the route first item of the array will work as "body" of the sms content. When someone go to the route again, 2nd item of the array will be worked as "body". Just like this the process will continue until it reaches to the last item of the array.

Is there any easy solution for me

Comment: Well instead of `[1]` you could remember that array index in the database, increment it, save it back. Make sure it's not out of bounds. Have you tried anything? Just post whatever you tried, others can google your question and learn from your code.

Comment: I want to try but its not coming to my head! @PeterKrebs

Comment: If you have any idea inside your head please share your idea with sample code that will better for me @PeterKrebs

Comment: You don't know how to increment a variable? You don't know how to save to and load from the database? You can look at PHP and Laravel tutorials for that. I don't have time to write that for you, sorry. See [how much research is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Looking at tutorials is on that list.

Comment: Thank you @PeterKrebs I already solved my own problem thanks for the suggestion

Comment: FYI you are allowed to answer your own question so that it may help others.